# Newline when using asp.net visible=false

Tags: asp.net, render, visible

when using asp.net´s visible=false e.g. for a htmlgenericcontrol asp.net renders a newline for a control that is set visible=false.

How to prevent this behavior?

I just have a

```
<ul> and then 

<li runat="server" id="x"></li> 
<li runat="server" id="x"></li> 
<li runat="server" id="x"></li>
```

So one `<li>` per line. If I set one or all li´s to visible=false by code I get newlines instead of "Nothing"

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question and post the part of your `aspx` page that is displaying the problem?

Comment: I just have a <ul> and then 

<li runat="server" id="x"></li>
<li runat="server" id="x"></li>
<li runat="server" id="x"></li>

So a <li> per line. If I set one or all li´s to visible=false by code I get newlines instead of "Nothing"

Comment: Can you _edit_ you question and put that in, so I can see it properly?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is no white space (spaces, tabs, new lines) around the control in the `aspx` page.

Try the following, all in one line:

```
<ul><li runat="server" id="x"></li><li runat="server" id="x"></li><li runat="server" id="x"></li></ul>
```